# How to change Default View of a XIB file?

Tags: objective-c, view, xib

As we get the default storyboard after creating a project. Later I added a view controller class with XIB file. In XIB the default view is provided. I came to a situation where that default view need to be changed to another view. So how to do this without over writing on views?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand correctly, but to change default view in xib you have to:

1. open xib
2. Select "File's Owner"
3. View > Utilities > Show Connections Inspector
4. Change view outlet

Comment: No its not working that now. Write now i am adding the view over the main view in ViewDidLoad ... I want View did load to load another view instead of adding it manually